# Story of a human going to school to learn magic in space alongside kids from different planets

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

In this book there was a human boy who went to school in space with kids from different planets. He had 2 friends a girl and a boy. The male friend gets sick with some sort of virus early on in the story that spreads to everyone but the human, the other friends (I think her name was Hazel, but I'm not sure) and the Bully (some sort of octopi creature). The bully's mother was one of the teachers.

In the end it turned out that they were being attacked because this other being(?) wanted an item from the school. At the end of the book it turned out that the whole thing was just a test.

I read this in 5th grade back in 2015 I believe.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Comment: I read this in 5th grade back in 2015 i believe

Comment: I wonder where the author of this imaginative and original book got his idea from. Let me get this straight: a kid goes to wizard school, already this blindsides me -- but there's more: IT'S IN SPACE!!! Are we ready for such trailblazing ideas??? This makes me abandon writing my own novel about a SPACE COP -- NOT ONLY THAT BUT HE PLAYS BY HIS OWN RULES and this puts him into conflict with his cranky supervisor who is near retirement IN SPACE.

Comment: I would read something like that lol

Comment: @BlazingFire: Space Cop? I was almost finished anyway... Okay, I'll proceed.

Comment: @releseabe make sure Space Cop gets a rookie partner. Maybe an alien.

Comment: I feel like i should add that i don't remember the title or author of this book,  so if anyone knows it please let me know.  I have to make sure this book wasn't a fever dream lol

Comment: @OrganicMarble Kind of a spoiler, but he does. Interestingly, he is a Xenomorph who when he burst from the Space Cop's chest  (which the cop survived obviously - ugly scar however) only eggmorphed a couple of people and then saw the light and wanted to become a cop to make up for it. Space Cop and he joke around a lot about the time he was in the coma and sometimes, joker that the Xeno is, he will wake up the guy from a nap by extruding his inner jaw almost to the human's face. When they play good cop/bad cop the Xeno is always the bad cop and, boy, do suspects talk fast.

Comment: @BlazingFire: My book is called Space Cop and Xenomorph.

Comment: Oh cool! But i meant tge story in my original question lol

Comment: I'm starting to believe this story was a fever dream